# Error: "Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: tslib_1 is not defined" while executing puppeteer test

Tags: typescript, jestjs, puppeteer

I have written a puppeteer test case where I am trying to read card title as soon as it matches with specific id I mentioned.
As soon as I try to invoke the test, It is throwing error that

> Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: tslib_1 is not defined

Rest of tests written in test suite work fine. it is breaking only with this test case.

The piece of code I wrote

```
it('TC Verify ingested job moved to approve lane', async () => {
    await Promise.all([networkWaitHelper.waitForNetworkIdle(page, 500, 5)]);
    await page.waitForSelector(DISPLAY_JOB_UI.DATAOPS_MODULE);
    await page.click(DISPLAY_JOB_UI.DATAOPS_MODULE);
    await Promise.all([networkWaitHelper.waitForNetworkIdle(page, 500, 5)]);
    await page.reload({ waitUntil: ['networkidle0', 'domcontentloaded'] });
    await Promise.all([networkWaitHelper.waitForNetworkIdle(page, 500, 5)]);
    await page.waitForSelector(DISPLAY_JOB_UI.DATAOPS_MODULE);
    await page.click(DISPLAY_JOB_UI.DATAOPS_MODULE);
    await Promise.all([networkWaitHelper.waitForNetworkIdle(page, 500, 5)]);
    await page.waitFor(4000);
    currentProcessingJobId='';
    expect(
      await page.evaluate(async (cuurentJobId) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let count = 0;
          const polling = setInterval(() => {
            count += 1;
            const approvedJobID1 = page
              .$eval(
                MULTIPLE_FILES_NEW_SUBMISSION_JOB_PO.JOB_CARD_APPROVE_ID,
                (element) => element.textContent.trim()
              )
              .then((approvedJobID) => {
                if (count === 10 || cuurentJobId === approvedJobID) {
                  clearInterval(polling);
                  resolve(approvedJobID);
                }
              });
          }, 60000);
        });
      }, currentProcessingJobId)
    ).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

In this code I am trying to do polling to periodically check as soon as my first approved card jobid=== cuurentJobId

Can you please help what could be the issue that I am receiving this error.

Comment: do you set `noEmitHelpers` in your tsconfig?

Comment: No , I didn't set that property in my config.